# I am getting following error: TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable

Tags: robotframework, appium-android, python-3.8

I am getting following error: TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable

```
*** Settings ***

Library        AppiumLibrary
Resource       ../../Resources/Library.robot

Documentation    Test Cases for Login module
# Test Setup    User_open_application
# Test Teardown     User_close_application
default tags    DFLT
force tags     ALL_TC
test timeout     2mins

*** Test Cases ***
TC_001- Application start and close
#  [Setup]    User_Open_Application
#  log    ${Res}
[Tags]    Regression
User_open_application
${username_text} =    Read_Element_Locator    login.username_textbox_xpath
${paswword_text} =    Read_Element_Locator    login.password_textbox_xpath
${send_button} =    Read_Element_Locator    login.login_button_id
${account_section} =    Read_Element_Locator    login.account_button_xpath
${logout} =    Read_Element_Locator    login.logout_xpath
Input Text    xpath=${username_text}    globaladmin
Input Text    xpath=${paswword_text}    Dassen!985
Click Element    id=${send_button}
Sleep    30
capture page screenshot  D:/pycharm/PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.4/camobile/Snapshots/TC_001.png
Click Element    xpath=${account_section}
Click Element    xpath=${logout}
sleep    5
User_close_application
#[Teardown]    User_Close_application
```

I am getting following error: TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable ,while executing the robotframework (python version 3.8)

Comment: We need to know where the error happens. On what keyword? Did it generated log.html?

Comment: Status: FAIL (critical)
Message: TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable
00:00:30.619KEYWORD Library . User_open_application
00:00:00.008KEYWORD ${username_text} = Library . Read_Element_Locator login.username_textbox_xpath
Start / End / Elapsed: 20200422 14:40:47.847 / 20200422 14:40:47.855 / 00:00:00.008
00:00:00.008KEYWORD ${result} = Locators . Read Locator From Json ${JsonPath}
Start / End / Elapsed: 20200422 14:40:47.847 / 20200422 14:40:47.855 / 00:00:00.008
14:40:47.855 FAIL TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

You have some problem in your user keyword `Read_Element_Locator`.
Seems to be in this step:

```
${result} = Locators . Read Locator From Json ${JsonPath}
```